# Hexadecimal QString representation to Unsigned char array

Tags: c++, string, qt, qt-creator, qstring

A QString with some user input contains a MAC address, for instance `"68F542F9AB22"`. I need to convert the QString to unsigned char array[6] of numbers, not the ASCII representation. So for the `QString 68F542F9AB22` the unsigned char array at first position should be 104.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can iterate over your QString and cut it into pieces of two and then use QString::toUShort(&ok,16), which will give you a ushort of your hex String.

Someting like

```
for(int i=0;i<6;++i)
{
     QString hexString = yourstring.mid(i*2,2);
     bool ok = false;
     yourBuf[i] = (unsigned char) hexString.toUShort(&ok,16);
     //if not ok, handle error
}
```

You shoud do some checks for the correct length of your input string and do some error handling on conversion errors.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks!. Yes I do checks for the QString to be a valid hexadecimal string first.

Comment: Or convert once `toULongLong` and ignore the top 16 bits as they're zero.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in the following way:

```
QString s("68F542F9AB22");
assert(s.size() % 2 == 0);

std::vector<unsigned char> array;
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i += 2)
{
  QString num = s.mid(i, 2);
  bool ok = false;
  array.push_back(num.toUInt(&ok, 16));
  assert(ok);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
QString s  = "68F542F9AB22";
unsigned char array[6];

if (s.length() % 2 == 0) { // test string length is even
    for (unsigned long i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i += 2) {
        QString chunk = s.mid(i,2);
        bool ok;
        array[i/2] = static_cast<unsigned char>(chunk.toInt(&ok,16));
    }
}
```

Note that the above code works only for even strings (but for MAC address, it's ok).

And to test the result you may use :

```
for (unsigned long i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i ++) {
    std::cout<<"Array ["<<i<<"] = "<<static_cast<unsigned long>(array[i])<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hex to `long long` is a single operation and will convert up to 64 bits. That's sufficient for an 48 bits MAC. So:

```
bool ok = false;
auto result = input.toULongLong(&ok,16);
for(int i=5;i>=0;--i)
{
   buf[i] = result & 0xFF;
   result >>= 8;
}
```

Comment: Only for 64bit machines long long is 64 bits right?

Comment: @MABC: It's _at least_ 64 bits. On a 64 bits machine, you might find `long` is 64 bits and `long long` could then be 128 bits. This code relies only on the minimum size, not the exact size.